# Accessing admin panel after deploying local MAMP

Tags: admin, mamp, deployment, 404

I've moved my site from a local install to my server. I'm pretty new at this, so hopefully I've followed the right course:

What I did:

- Edited db.php to reflect the changes
- Edited index.php to point at the craft folder
- Had to change the siteUrl in craft_info because it would only show the Craft 404 page (siteUrl was still on localhost)

I can see the correct rendered pages now, but as soon as I type /admin or /index.php/admin or /index.php?p=admin I get an Apache 404 error on the /admin/login url

So what should i do now?

Comment: Is the 404 error a Craft styles error or an Apache error?

Comment: That's an Apache error

Comment: Can you post your genera.php config file?

Comment: If it's an Apache error, it's not making it to Craft at all. Is the domain you're using pointing to Craft's public html folder in your vhost file?

Comment: It did in the local setup Brad (it worked), but does that matter on the remote server? if it does I'm not sure what I need to check. It works for the regular pages, but not for the admin.

Comment: Aaron, the general.php file is empty

Comment: What's in the .htaccess file in the public html folder?

Comment: The standard stuff Brad, no changes. Could the problem be that the folder setup local did not reflect the server? I used public_html, but the server uses www

Answer (score 1):

Apparently what I did was correct, because now it works. I had some EE files right next to the index.php files and these messed things up for some reason. Probably the admin.php file.

At least now I know it's easy to deploy Craft with the three steps I mentioned above